# Python TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list

Tags: python

I have two lines in my program that seems fairly simple but has been given me some headache

here it is

```
costs = sum([map(int, f.readline().strip().split(' ')) for i in range(8)], [])
awards = sum([map(int, f.readline().strip().split(' ')) for i in range(8)], [])
```

It gives me the error: **TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list**

It seems to me that it something to do with python 2 to python 3 version but I can't figure it out!

I am stuck in this for several hours and cant find a solution. Any help ?

Comment: **Don't use `sum` to flatten a list of lists**. It's highly inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct. In Python 2, `map` returned a list. In Python 3, it returns a special iterable that lazily maps over the collection. Simply convert this iterable to a list explicitly.

```
costs = sum((list(map(int, f.readline().strip().split(' '))) for i in range(8)), [])
```

Note also that by using parentheses rather than brackets on the generator expression, we can avoid producing an intermediate list.

```
sum([... for i in range(8)])
```

This produces a list fully in memory and then sums the values.

```
sum(... for i in range(8))
```

This iterates over the range and produces a sum as we go, never making an intermediate list.

Comment: Apart from all the intermediate lists generated internally by `sum`!

Comment: ... ... ... Yeah, that's fair. I didn't think about that xD

Comment: You should **really** not use `sum` here

Answer (score 2):

Instead of summing lists in this fashion you can use chain:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(
    map(int, f.readline().strip().split(' ')) for i in range(8)))
```

This will be much more memory efficient, and for larger values of your loop it may become significantly faster as well.

Using `sum` causes many temporary lists to be made ... if we are using `sum(L, [])` then internally this is producing many intermediate lists (of lists)

```
sum(L, []) ->

  tmp = [] + L[0]
  tmp = tmp + L[1]
  ...
  tmp = tmp + L[7]
```

Every step of this sum, discards the previous `tmp` while constructing a new one.